# Google Sheet - Ranges

Tags: python, range, jira, google-sheets-api, gspread

My code is scraping values from jira and adding them to google sheets. At the moment it can get the infomation I need and enter them in 1 colum in google sheets.

How do I get the information in two separate columns?

Thanks!

```
# coding=utf-8

from jira.client import JIRA
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPES = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("blank", SCOPES)
connection = gspread.authorize(credentials)

options = {'server': 'https://jira.blank.com/'}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('blank', 'blabk'))
projects = jira.projects()

worksheet = connection.open("blank").sheet1

cell_list = worksheet.range('A2:A151')

for cell, x in zip(cell_list, jira.search_issues('filter=13360')):
issue = x
cell.value = x, issue.fields.summary

# Update in batch
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)

print("Done updating, check the spreadsheet now")
```

Answer (score 2):

This line of code here fetches only from column A:

```
cell_list = worksheet.range('A2:A151')
```

If you want to fetch to other columns like B, C,etc do it like

```
cell_list = worksheet.range('A2:B') or

cell_list = worksheet.range('A2:B10')
```

You can read more about this in [Reading Cells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading).